# Avoiding repetition - Android Development

Tags: android, algorithm

The question might look strange. Let us suppose,we are making a products selling application. We would have different categories for products like PCs,Laptops,ps4,ps3,xbox etc. Now here is the thing. Each product category would require its own adapter,fragment,xml files and webservices. But I am thinking,that I would be better to create an algorithm where you wouldn't have an adapter design repetition for every category,but instead create somehow a central adapter and use it for all categories viewing. I am trying to be as much professional as I can. As an engineer,I know that repetition isn't a good thing. How do you go around this?

Comment: you have to at least try it first! I don't know what is your problem now, of course it's better to use one layout and one fragment if you can and you are sure there are no design or logic differences between the categories, but you didn't say what is your problem! just do it this way

Comment: Why would them require its own classes? Is there a different behaviour or look and feel for each one? Those are the questions I would as myself.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will some things on my own:).